# In-App product type for downloading video within the app

Tags: ios, video, in-app-purchase

In my application I want to implement the in-app purchase to download the video. Some one will upload the video into my app. My app will make some changes into the video and post it back to all the users of the app. Now this modified video can be purchased(download) by any user. 
I am confusing in selecting the product type for my requirement. I have followed [In-app purchase of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267068/in-app-purchase-of-video) but still in dilemma. 
Please suggest me the valid product type for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For users to be able to watch the video as many times as they want, go with Non-Consumable.

Comment: What about for downloading the video?

Comment: The same. It's up to you basically, but users generally want to be able to re-use their purchases (exceptions of Consumable purchases are more often in games, eg. buying 10 arrows that you use and have to re-buy).

Comment: In iTunes connect when creating the product it says "A consumable In-App Purchase must be purchased every time the user downloads it." and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132011/in-app-purchase-consumable-product?rq=1 says my product related to consumable. Please comment.

Comment: Again, it's up to you.
If you think the user should pay again to re-download a video, you can do that.
If it's not something that expires (like arrows used in a game) then the purchase should be non-consumable (the user buys it once and then it is available for him without paying again).

Comment: Imagine you are your app's user. You buy a video and you download it.
After a while you delete it because you need disk space.
Later, you want to show it to a friend.
Do you think you should pay again to re-download what you have already bought?

If you answer yes then make it Consumable, else Non-Consumable. 
It's entirely up to you (although Apple may disagree with your choice during the review process - rare, but it can happen).